# How do I prove that a torus and a product of circles are diffeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The exercise looks like this:

- Prove that the $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ and $S^1$ are diffeomorphic.
- Prove that $\mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n$ and $(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)^n$ are diffeomorphic.
- Deduce that $\mathbb T^n$ is diffeomorphic to  $(S^1)^n $.

What I did so far:

I took $\phi:$$ \mathbb R  \to S^1 $ where $\phi(x)=(cos(2\pi x),sin(2\pi x))$.

$\pi$ :$\mathbb R \to \mathbb R/\mathbb Z\ $ a surjective map

and then $\psi$ : $ \mathbb R/\mathbb Z \to S^1 $.

So $\phi$ is a composition of these two maps.... I thought if I prove that the composition is a diffeomorphism it'll be the answer!

Thank you.

Comment: Please use MathJax. As for the question, well, a first step would be to define a map from one to the other which might turn out to be a diffeomorphism. Would you see one?

Comment: Were you successful in proving that $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ and $S^1$ are diffeomorphic? If so, did that give you any ideas for generalization?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg i did for the one dimension but i m not sure about it.would you ant to see it !!

Comment: @LeeMosher not yet...like i did some but i m not sure about it, for generalization no idea !!

Comment: Let me suggest that you edit your question to add what you just told me, and with additional details explaining what you did in the case $n=1$. That would improve your question, and help you to avoid close votes.

Comment: @LeeMosher okay,thank you...i did the edit

Comment: Well, for the $n=1$ case, you cannot just write down some symbols like $\phi$, $\psi$, $\pi$. You must write actual formulas. To prove that $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1$, you must write an actual formula for an actual function $f : \mathbb R / \mathbb Z \to S^1$ (and then prove its a homeomorphism).  You can feel free to use any other symbol in place of $f$, but you *cannot* skip the formula. Without that, you haven't done the $n=1$ case, and you won't be able to do the higher cases either.

Comment: @LeeMosher thank you for your time and im sorry not being clear enough ....so, i took  $\phi:$$ \mathbb R / \mathbb Z \to S^1 $ where $\phi(x)=(cos(2\pi x),sin(2\pi x))$ 

 - and $\pi$ :$\mathbb R \to \mathbb R/\mathbb Z\ $ a surjective map
 - so then $\psi$ : $ \mathbb R/\mathbb Z \to S^1 $
 - so $\phi$ is a compostion of this two maps ...i thought if i prove that the composition its diffeomorphisme it ll be answer !!....or i have to prove that $\phi$ is a homeomorphic first like you said


thank you

Comment: Again, you should edit your question to include that new information. That will *greatly* improve your question.

Comment: @LeeMosher okay ...but, is it right what i did !!

Answer (score 1):

You have too much in this question: even just the case $n=1$ needs work, so I'll give you a critique of the $n=1$ case. The main problem with your approach is lack of rigor regarding quotient maps and quotient topologies.

First, regarding the function $\pi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ you need not just that it is surjective, but you need that it is a quotient map.

Second, you need to apply the universal property of quotient maps to the composition formula $\phi = \psi \circ \pi$; from that, you can deduce that $\psi$ is also a quotient map. (You should also correct your description/formula for $\phi$: its domain is $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$).

Third, you need to prove that $\psi$ is one-to-one, and from that you can finally deduce that $\psi$ is a homeomorphism.

Here's just a hint for the general case: proceed similarly, starting from 
$$\phi(x_1,...,x_n) = \biggl(\bigl(\cos(2\pi x_1),\sin(2 \pi x_1)\bigr),...,\bigl((\cos(2\pi x_n),\sin(2\pi x_n)\bigr)\biggr)
$$